# Get the last modified date of a remote file

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I would like to get the last modified date of a remote file by means of curl. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [php's article](http://ar.php.net/filemtime):

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```

filemtime() is the key here. But I'm not sure if you can get the last modified date of a **remote** file, since the server should send it to you... Maybe in the HTTP headers?

Comment: From the manual: "As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with *some* URL wrappers."

Comment: For my experience this method doesn't work always (it dependes on your php.ini) so native get_headers worked better for me.

Comment: filemtime() only works with files on the same server. Use $ch = curl_init("https://domian.com/dir/file.htm");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $retcode= curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
  curl_close($ch);

Comment: Why is this marked as the correct answer? As @MarkAntonyAgius notes, filemtime() won't work for remote files.

Answer (score 44):

You could probably do something like this using [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php):

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.example.com/filename.txt');

//don't fetch the actual page, you only want headers
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

//stop it from outputting stuff to stdout
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// attempt to retrieve the modification date
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result === false) {
    die (curl_error($curl)); 
}

$timestamp = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
if ($timestamp != -1) { //otherwise unknown
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp); //etc
}
```

Comment: I've notice that this code sometimes doesn't work, native php get_headers works better for me.

Answer (score 26):

In PHP you can use the native function `get_headers()`:

```
<?php
$h = get_headers($url, 1);

$dt = NULL;
if (!($h || strstr($h[0], '200') === FALSE)) {
    $dt = new \DateTime($h['Last-Modified']);//php 5.3
}
```

Comment: "If" condition didn't work properly... `if(!$h || strpos($h[0], '200') !== false){` works better for me!

Comment: dino is correct. It looks like a `!` operator was omitted in the above code by accident. The if statement should really be `if (!(!$h || strstr($h[0], '200') === FALSE)) {`

Comment: Might want to combine and add the lowercase code from Pons to this as well. `if(strtolower(trim($k))=='last-modified')`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes header come with different upper lower case, this should help:

```
function remoteFileData($f) {
    $h = get_headers($f, 1);
    if (stristr($h[0], '200')) {
        foreach($h as $k=>$v) {
            if(strtolower(trim($k))=="last-modified") return $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can activate receiving the headers of the reply with `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true)`. You can also turn on CURLOPT_NOBODY to only receive the headers, and after that explode the result by \r\n and interpret the single headers. The header `Last-Modified` is the one that you are interested in.

Comment: Yep - just request the headers

Comment: Assuming they send the Last-Modified header

Comment: This seems to have a problem with 403 - forbidden - responses - it doesn't seem to get access to the header. Don' think there is a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

By editing h4kuna's answer I created this:

```
$fileURL='http://www.yahoo.com';
$headers = get_headers($fileURL, 1);
$date = "Error";
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($headers); echo "</pre>";
if ( $headers && (strpos($headers[0],'200') !== FALSE) ) {
    $time=strtotime($headers['Last-Modified']);
    $date=date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $time);
}
echo 'file: <a href="'.$fileURL.'" target="_blank">'.$fileURL.'</a> (Last-Modified: '.$date.')<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work, from [web developer forum](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=81776)

```
<? $last_modified = filemtime("content.php"); print("Last Updated - ");
print(date("m/d/y", $last_modified)); ?

// OR

$last_modified = filemtime(__FILE__);
```

the link provides some useful insite on you can use them

Answer (score 0):

Had to solve similiar issue, but for me download once a day was enough so I compared just the modify day of the local (downloaded) cache file. The remote file had no Last-Modified header.

```
$xml = 'test.xml';
if (is_file($xml) || date('d', filemtime($xml)) != date('d')) {
    $xml = file_get_contents(REMOTE_URL);
}
```