# ftp_ssl_connect with implicit ftp over tls

Tags: php, ftp, ssl, ftps

Can ftp_ssl_connect handle Implicit FTP over TLS?  By default it uses explicit.

I'm trying to upload to a server that accepts only Implicit ftp over tls on port 990; has anybody run into this as of yet?  How did you fix it?

Comment: IIRC, it doesn't support implicit.  I think I've run in to that a few times myself.

Comment: You might want to try the curl functions instead. I'm not sure if this will work for implicit but generally the options there give you a bit more control.

Comment: thanks for the edit and comments

Comment: I fixed it by running an external Perl script (using Net::FTPSSL) via exec(), not the cleanest of solutions but if you're happy to mix languages it might help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ftp_ssl_connect is only explicit

if you need implicit, use curl

```
$fp = fopen($path, 'r');
$ftp_server = 'ftps://'.$server.'/'.$filename; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$user.':'.$pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
//var_dump(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: If you need to debug, add:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

Answer (score 11):

Based on frustrum and Steven Jeffries's answers I've extended it further. This reuses the curl connection and has some directory listing functions, including one to sort files by last modified.

This is for PHP 7, for lower you will have to rewrite the <=> operator line.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implicit FTP 
 * @author Nico
 * Based on
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589730/ftp-ssl-connect-with-implicit-ftp-over-tls
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845220/get-the-last-modified-date-of-a-remote-file
 */
class ImplicitFtp {

    private $server;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $curlhandle;

    public function __construct($server, $username, $password) {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->curlhandle = curl_init();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if (!empty($this->curlhandle))
            @curl_close($this->curlhandle);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $remote remote path
     * @return resource a cURL handle on success, false on errors.
     */
    private function common($remote) {
        curl_reset($this->curlhandle);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftps://' . $this->server . '/' . $remote);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
        return $this->curlhandle;
    }

    public function download($remote, $local = null) {
        if ($local === null) {
            $local = tempnam('/tmp', 'implicit_ftp');
        }

        if ($fp = fopen($local, 'w')) {
            $this->curlhandle = self::common($remote);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

            curl_exec($this->curlhandle);

            if (curl_error($this->curlhandle)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return $local;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function upload($local, $remote) {
        if ($fp = fopen($local, 'r')) {
            $this->curlhandle = self::common($remote);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

            curl_exec($this->curlhandle);
            $err = curl_error($this->curlhandle);

            return !$err;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get file/folder names
     * @param string $remote
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function listnames($remote) {
        if (substr($remote, -1) != '/')
            $remote .= '/';
        $this->curlhandle = self::common($remote);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($this->curlhandle);

        if (curl_error($this->curlhandle)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $files = explode("\r\n", trim($result));
            return $files;
            return $local;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file/folder names ordered by modified date
     * @param string $remote
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function listbydate($remote) {
        $files = $this->listnames($remote);
        if (empty($files))
            return null;
        $filedata = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {

            $this->curlhandle = self::common($remote . '/' . $file);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_FILETIME, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $result = curl_exec($this->curlhandle);

            if ($result) {
                $timestamp = curl_getinfo($this->curlhandle, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
                $fileobj = array();
                $fileobj['name'] = $file;
                $fileobj['lastmodified'] = ($timestamp != -1) ? date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp) : null;
                $filedata[] = $fileobj;
            }
        }

        usort($filedata, function ($item1, $item2) {
            return date($item2['lastmodified']) <=> date($item1['lastmodified']);
        });

        return $filedata;
    }



    /**
     * Get file/folder raw data
     * @param string $remote
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function rawlist($remote) {
        if (substr($remote, -1) != '/')
            $remote .= '/';
        $this->curlhandle = self::common($remote);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($this->curlhandle);

        if (curl_error($this->curlhandle)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $files = explode("\n", trim($result));
            return $files;
            return $local;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file/folder parsed data into an array
     * @param string $remote
     * @return array[]
     */
    public function list($remote) {
        $this->curlhandleildren = $this->rawlist($remote);
        if (!empty($this->curlhandleildren)) {
            $items = array();
            foreach ($this->curlhandleildren as $this->curlhandleild) {
                $chunks = preg_split("/\s+/", $this->curlhandleild);
                list($item['rights'], $item['number'], $item['user'], $item['group'], $item['size'], $item['month'], $item['day'], $item['time']) = $chunks;
                array_splice($chunks, 0, 8);
                $item['name'] = trim(implode(" ", $chunks));
                $item['type'] = $chunks[0]{0} === 'd' ? 'directory' : 'file';
                $items[] = $item;
            }
            return $items;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `private function common($remote)` be `private static function common($remote)` as you call it using PHP's static method operator `self::common($remote);`?

Comment: @tonix self:: calls to non-statics is allowed - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218182/php-calling-self-on-a-non-static-method

Comment: @NicoWesterdale  - on call the download function I am just getting the file name from the remote server. How I will move files from the FTP server to the local directory?

Comment: I suggest to change $files = explode("\r\n", trim($result)); to $files = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($result)); 

Apps/server running on linux will return the result not in an array if you use the \r\n

Comment: I'm trying to delete a file using this code. But I can't succeed in it. Tried `curl_setopt($this->curlhandle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');`, but files are not being deleted on the ftps server. Any idea how to?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who happens to google upon this page and wants a quick solution:

I expanded on frustrum's answer and made a simple class for basic upload/download using this method. I hope it helps!

```
<?php

class ImplicitFtp {

    private $server;
    private $username;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($server, $username, $password) {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function download($remote, $local = null) {
        if ($local === null) {
            $local = tempnam('/tmp', 'implicit_ftp');
        }

        if ($fp = fopen($local, 'w')) {
            $ftp_server = 'ftps://' . $this->server . '/' . $remote;
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

            curl_exec($ch);

            if (curl_error($ch)) {
                curl_close($ch);
                return false;
            } else {
                curl_close($ch);
                return $local;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function upload($local, $remote) {
        if ($fp = fopen($local, 'r')) {
            $ftp_server = 'ftps://' . $this->server . '/' . $remote;
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

            curl_exec($ch);
            $err = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return !$err;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```