# PHP Calling self on a non-static method

Tags: php, class, methods, self, non-static

Why is the 'self'-call to a non-satic method in this example working?

```
class A{

    protected function aNonStaticMethod(){
        return __class__;
    }

    public function aEcho(){
        echo self::aNonStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: As nearly everywhere described and shown in examples (eg http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.static.php) self is used in a static method context. I haven't found examples where self is used without a 'public/protected/private/final static function method()'. So may I further like to know, if that use shown above is wrong.

Comment: `self::` is not limited to static context.
Neither is `parent::` nor `SomeParentClass::`.

Comment: @Kontrollfreak because calling non-static method statically does not make sense in PHP version > 4 ... :-) also it won't be supported in future - check my answer :)

Comment: @jave.web Please be aware that I wrote `Some**Parent**Class::` and *not* `SomeClass::`. That means the call to `SomeParentClass::someMethod()` is made from a non-static context that extends `SomeParentClass`. And this would be perfectly valid.

Comment: @Kontrollfreak I was referring to your "Why shouldn't it?" question :) Of course, logically, static calls for static things are for all context - I use it too :) However I've added a note about that to my answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Calling non-static method statically

Theoretically it should **not** work, but as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/18t7j7/why_the_fuck_does_php_allow_calling_nonstatic/c8hr39q) comment says:

> There was no static keyword in php4 but php4 did allow for static
> calls. To maintain backwards compatibility this was left in when the
> static keyword was added in php5.

This comment is supported by [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reclassify_e_strict#calling_non-static_methods_statically) official php.net wiki:

> This is already deprecated if the call occurs from an instance method.
> Not annotating methods as static is an obsolete PHP4-ism.

You really should not call non-static method statically - it does not make sense (if there is a **`static`** keyword).

#### Avoid calling non-static methods statically *completely*!

...because a) it is a **bad approach** and b) the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) say:

> **Caution**
>
> In PHP 5, calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

AND

> **Warning**
>
> In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning. Support for calling non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.

## Using `::` operator for non-static calls - may be a good approach!

As @Kontrollfreak pointed out and as [this docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) say the `::` operator is not limited to static calls:

> the **double colon**, is a token that allows access to static, constant,
> **and overridden properties or methods of a class**

So it is OK if you reference this way a method or properties from a **parent class** - which is *not limited* to a direct parent.

#### EDIT: do not mistake this for Fascade etc. software patterns!

During writing this answer I forgot to mention that there might be cases, when the call is static, but internally it is calling dynamic method - for more info see patterns like [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) or [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

**However do NOT mistake these with issue described above!** (issue above is about using *direct* static call on dynamic thing that should be called dynamically, these patterns are about calling static methods statically, which then may dynamically invoke something dynamic (internally)).

Comment: Even if you're not using `self` or `parent`, the double colon `::` doesn't necessarily mean the call is (or should be) static. How else would you reference a method of a parent class that is not your *direct* parent? See what I mean: [Sandbox Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4029741e62fc9761acd9bcf6bce791192baf653)

Comment: @Kontrollfreak Yes, that is true, but only in the way you've described, using it to call class' own non-static method/property is a bad approach :) But thank you for pointing that out - I've added this note to my answer :) Also I've removed the self/parent chapter - I know this approach, I just forgot about it, sorry :P

Comment: You write it's bad approach to use `self::` on normal methods. Is that your opinion or can back that claim up?

Comment: @Kontrollfreak - I don't want to be missunderstood - using self:: is bad approach **only** if you reference **class'-own** ***non-***static method - it is explained in the first part of my answer, but also in the latter one - "static, constant and overriden..." - since calling class' own non-static-non-constant things is not overriding nor constant calling nor static calling - using `::` operator itself does not fit into this definition, Calling "my own" non-static should be done through `->` ... So answer to both of your questions is yes - I think so & docs support what I say.

Comment: I think you're mixing the issues here. Yes, [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) say calling non-static methods statically is deprecated. But using `self::someNonStaticMethod()` **isn't** a static call. Using `self::` is *more specific* than using `$this->`, as the former always refers to its origin class. I prepared another example with [`self::`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de2edb50a2b409b92d7714ea10b6014673176103) and [`$this->`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4757589885dcbd796e9bd41ed23a25f33adaf9b4) to show the difference.

Comment: @Kontrollfreak Well that is sort of overriding - but backwards - so you are right on this one - however it still **does** fit to what I said... What I mean is if you would really call your own not-overriden (in any way) method with `::` - that whould be wrong.

Comment: Indeed, it is a difference between $this-> and self:: for non static calls. However, even if it works, using it is a bad practice. When you extend a class, you expect that the functions you override will be used. An extended class should not behave in a way that is unpredictable. It hides multiple responsibilities behind the name of a function. It would be cleaner to just have a private method you call with this if you do not intend to have it overwritten. For those reasons, this language feature is unsafe to use, especially in a team, because it brings no real value, but adds complexity.

Answer (score 8):

In your simple example $this and self is interchangable. But be aware of the different method resolving when dealing with inheritance (i added static for completeness):

```
class A {
    protected function aNonStaticMethod(){
        return __class__;
    }

    public function selfEcho(){
        echo self::aNonStaticMethod();
    }

    public function staticEcho(){
        echo static::aNonStaticMethod();
    }

    public function thisEcho(){
        echo $this->aNonStaticMethod();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected function aNonStaticMethod(){
        return __class__;
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->selfEcho(); // A
$b->staticEcho(); // B
$b->thisEcho(); // B
```