# last modification date of a webpage using php

Tags: php

I want to get last modification date of different webpage using php
for example last modification date of google , yahoo , or a weblog or ...

I used the code below :

```
echo "document.write('".date( "F d, Y. H:i:s a", filemtime($filename)));
```

but it works only for files not webpages ! and for web pages it  returns something like this:

> Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for http://www.mst.edu/ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\api.php on line 56

```
document.write('January 01, 1970. 01:00:00 am');
```

Comment: Check this out...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845220/get-the-last-modified-date-of-a-remote-file

Answer (score 1):

The [manual for `filemtime`](http://php.net/filemtime#refsect1-function.filemtime-notes) states:

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with ***some*** URL wrappers. Refer to [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/wrappers) to determine which wrappers support [stat()](http://php.net/stat) family of functionality.

It also states for the [http:// wrapper](http://php.net/wrappers.http) that it does not support stat().

So you can't use `filemtime` to get what you want. However, sites *may* expose their last modified time in the `Last-Modified` HTTP response header. For this, you could use the built-in `get_headers`:

```
$headers = get_headers('http://www.mst.edu/');
var_dump($headers['Last-Modified']);
```

Or you could use cURL, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845234/283078).