# getting modified time of a remote file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having some problems with the two functions `filemtime()` and `file_get_contents`

I have this variable

```
$dataFileName = 'http://www.dota2u.com/newd2u/longpoll/data.php';
```

and this

```
$modifiedAt = filemtime( $dataFileName );
```

The weird thing is than I can't get the `filemtime()` now, but if I do this:

```
$dataFileName = 'data.php';
```

it works... the problem is that I need the full path. Is there a solution?

Comment: File operations like filemtime do not work with stream wrappers, you must use local paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the last modified date of a remote file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845220/get-the-last-modified-date-of-a-remote-file)